# How to crawl a list of some data+links and get these links data

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm setting up a PDF database for a webpage I'm working on and I need to crawl a webpage that's something like this list of dictionaries:

1. Dictonary 1

   - Name: Alice
   - Surname: Smith
   - More info: Address1
   - Info: (www.url.com) -> I need to follow this link, parse its content and add the info to this dictionary
2. Dictionary 2

   - Name: Bob
   - Surname: Baggings
   - More info: Address
   - Info: (www.url.com) -> I need to follow this link, parse its content and add the info to this dictionary
3. Dictionary *n*

   - Name: Name
   - Surname: Surname
   - More info: Address
   - Info: (www.url.com) -> I need to follow this link, parse its content and add the info to this dictionary

So on and so forth. How can I do this using scrapy?

```
import scrapy

class SpiderDoesThings(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'my_name'
    start_urls = [my_urls]

def parse(self, response):
    for item in response.css(filter1):
        link = item.css(filter2)
        meta_data = {
            'name': item.css(filter3)
        }
        yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_additionalinfo, meta=meta_data)

def parse_additionalinfo(self, response):
    response.meta.update({'mynewinfo': response.css(filter4)
    yield response.meta
```

The code only returns the first dictionary of the list:

1. Dictonary 1

   - Name: Alice
   - Surname: ...
   - More info: ...
   - Info: (link) -> I need to follow this link and add the info to       this dictionary

I have tried adding the "no-filter=True" and it crawled the rest of the list, but it just kept crawling the same additional info. "Name", "Surname" and "More info" were correct though. Something like:

1. Dictonary 1

   - Name: Alice
   - Surname: Smith
   - More info: Address1
   - Info: parsed_info1
2. Dictionary 2

   - Name: Bob
   - Surname: Baggings
   - More info: Address
   - Info: parsed_info1
3. Dictionary *n*

   - Name: Name
   - Surname: Surname
   - More info: Address
   - Info: parsed_info1

Comment: I see no reason why it shouldn’t work. Any chance you can provide a reproducible example? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It worked, I was actually following the wrong link all this time.

Thank you!